# Ansible Wait_For Module

Tags: ansible

I created a playbook to reboot my remote servers. I use wait_for to wait for remote servers up before I continue. So I have the following code:

```
—-
- hosts: hostName
  tasks:
    - name: reboot
      shell: reboot
      async: 1
      poll: 0

    - name: wait for server to come up
      Local_action: wait_for
      args:
      host: hostName
      port: 22
      state: started
      delay: 10
      timeout: 600
```

My targeted server was up about 5 minutes after reboot was initiated. However, the playbook stacked at this play till it timed out and generated error.

My questions are:
 1. How doeS wait_for work here? Does it send ssh connection request to target host and time out if it cannot connect to the target host after 600 seconds? Or does it keep pinging the target host till it times out?
 2.What could be the problem I am having?

Answer (score 0):

You'll be better off using [wait_for_connection](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_connection_module.html#wait-for-connection-waits-until-remote-system-is-reachable-usable) in this case. For example, given the play is running at `- hosts: hostName`

```
- name: Wait 600 seconds, but only start checking after 10 seconds
  wait_for_connection:
    delay: 10
    timeout: 600
```

---

> Q: How does wait_for work here?

A: wait_for is waiting for a port to become available.

> Q: Does it send the ssh connection request to the target host and time out if it cannot connect to the target host after 600 seconds?

A: No. It's testing the port.

> Q: Does it keep pinging the target host till it times out?

A: No. It tries to create a socket. See [wait_for.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/utilities/logic/wait_for.py#L530)

```
s = socket.create_connection((host, port), connect_timeout)
```

> Q: What could be the problem I am having?

A: It's not clear from the data available. Do not run `wait_for` as `local_action`. Make sure the host rebooted successfully.

Comment: Thank you, @ Vladimir! I updated my question. My goal is to keep checking if the target server is up after reboot so can move on to next play.  I’ve checked wait_for_connection module you suggested. Yes, I probably should use this as it sends ping to my target host? So for wait_for, the play I current have is at my ansible playbook running server to check if socket hostName:22 is open after hostName is rebooted? How do I manually check if socket hostName:22 is open on my playbook running server? Sorry, I am not quite understand how socket works. So forgive me if my question sounds silly:-(